# How does copy() function shows this output in C++?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string str4 = "welcome";
    char str5[10];
    char str6[10];
    cout << str4 << endl;
    str4.copy(str5, str4.size());
    cout << str5 << endl;
    str4.copy(str6, 3);
    cout << str6 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know does this copy function copied in str5

Output shown to me is

```
welcome
welcome�v��`
wel
```

Comment: Reading from uninitialized objects is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: The counter question is why are you surprised at this?  Memory has to contain something, and uninitialised memory can contain anything.

Comment: `str4.copy(str5, str4.size());` doesn't copy the terminating `NUL` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Copy function simple copy number of bytes.
In your case:

1. str4 contains 'welcome' string and str4.size() return 7, but string terminator character '\0' is not included.
2. The copy function copy 7 bytes to the str5.
3. Now str5 contains 'welcome' string without string terminator '\0'.
4. Cout print all characters till '\0'. In your case it is random. If you reboot your PC it will print more or less characters after 'welcome'.
5. You should add '\0' after copy to the position str4.size().

Comment: `copy` never copies more characters than the string has, at least according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy